# How to convert float value in SQL?

Tags: sql

How to convert a value `1500` which is of float type in a table to `1.500000000+e02` using `SQL` query?

Comment: 1.500000000+e02 does not equal 1500. I'm not clear if you're asking how to divide the values by 10, or if you are talking about numeric presentation.

Comment: If you are talking about presentation, then `SELECT FORMAT(1500,'e9')` may be what you're looking for.

Comment: What type and what version of SQL are you using?

Comment: Got the solution friends. Thanks. It is:
convert(nvarchar(max),fieldName,2)